# Pickle error when I save a doc2vec model, AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I failed to use the callbacks to save model according to the [official documents]:https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/callbacks.html

AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'train_model..shf'

```py
    from random import shuffle
    from gensim.models.callbacks import CallbackAny2Vec
    from gensim.test.utils import get_tmpfile

    class shf(CallbackAny2Vec):
        def __init__(self, x, path_prefix):
            self.epoch = 0
            self.x = x
            self.path_prefix = path_prefix
        def on_epoch_begin(self, model):
            shuffle(self.x)

        def on_epoch_end(self, model):
            print("epoch:%s"%self.epoch)
            if self.epoch % 10 == 0:
                output_path = get_tmpfile('{}_epoch{}.model'.format(self.path_prefix, self.epoch))
                model.save(output_path)
            self.epoch += 1
    model_dm = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(min_count=1, window=10, size=size, sample=1e-3, negative=5, workers=3)
    model_dm.build_vocab(x_train + x_test)

    fun = shf(x_train, "\models")
    model_dm.train(x_train, total_examples=model_dm.corpus_count, epochs=100, callbacks=[fun])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the verbatim full error stack you're seeing in your question to help answerers see exactly what steps/lines-of-code are triggering the error.

But also, saving models with callbacks presents a number of problems, especially when you've defined a class purely locally (as with your `shf` class) which might not be available when the model is re-loaded. There's some discussion of the problem & workarounds in [an open `gensim` issue](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2136), and the library may choose to disable saving-of-callbacks entirely in the future (such that a callback is only specified, and in-effect, for the duration of a single call to `train()`).

In the meantime, that error you're getting might be something new in Python 3.x – catching the problem on save rather than load. And, if you defined your callback class in another module, that could be imported by name before saving (so that it could also be imported by name before re-loading), it might resolve your issue.

A few other notes about your setup:

- Shuffling before each training epoch is usually overkill with negligible benefit, especially with larger datasets or larger epoch counts. (If your original datasource has examples of similar category or vocabulary clumped together, then a single initial shuffle may still be helpful.)
- If you've done `build_vocab()` with a larger number of different documents than your later call to `train()`, then the `model_dm.corpus_count` isn't going to be the correct number of `total_examples`. (It's the total cached from `build_vocab()`, not the count of training examples.) As a result, learning-rate management and logged progress indicators will be slightly off. Also, the model will be initialized to know about words that may only appear in non-training documents. Parts of the model associated with such words will remain un-trained – because there are no examples of their usage provided during `train()` – which will probably cause worse model results than just ignoring them entirely.
- If you're calling `train()` with `epochs=100`, you might as well supply `epochs=100` when creating the model, as well, so that the model remembers that value as its default number of cycles (for example, if later calling `infer_vector()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and suggestions. I tried another way to implement the function. Although I haven't sovled this problem, it's very nice of you to answer me patiently. Thanks again.